# Best way to go from one light fixture over dining room table to two light fixtures?

Tags: electrical

I have one light over dining room table. Want to change to two lights. Do not want junction box where light that is getting removed.

Comment: A [7-port canopy](https://v1.techlighting.com/Products/Fixtures/Multi-Port-Chandeliers/FreeJack-Rectangle-Canopy-7-port) with your choice of pendants and heads?

Comment: A junction box is required for splices.  If no splice at the old light location, you don't need a box there.  You pull or cut the cable for the first light, then add a longer cable to the second light.  Just the two new boxes at the new light locations.  I also imagine your circuit will not be this easy.  If not could think about a three light idea.

Comment: You either need a junction box or rewire it from source. There's no third alternative.

Comment: An upside down T so the lamps hang from each end - fun balancing though... The THIRD alternative :)

Comment: What crip659 said, plus if space above is accessible attic it would acceptable to mount a face up box at the existing location, with extensions to new locations.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a junction box where you are removing one light, you'll need to remove the cable to that box, and the box - hopefully you can move it to whichever one of the two new box locations is closer to where the cable comes from.

This will likely involve major surgery on the ceiling for adequate access. Not a big deal, just accept the need for drywall repair to achieve the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to purchase a multi pendant fixture that attaches to the existing junction box.   Here are some an [examples](https://www.build.com/linear-pendants/c112865).  Use filters there to limit to two bulbs if you want.  Not a recommendation, just to illustrate.

If you want them both hanging straight from the ceiling and don't want the old box left behind you will need to break open the ceiling and hope the cable to the old box can be rerouted to reach one of the new locations.  If you have unfinished space above (preferably) or below that will help